# expand list when mouse hover on list - css list tree view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to build CSS basic list tree structure (UL-Li...) of multiple levels. I have managed up-to point where mouse hover on level 1 li, it shows its child ul-li and move back to its original position when mouse hover out. However it remove active class when level 1 even it has child elements so my question is how I bound to check if mouse is on $this child element and not hover out to level 2 and so on...

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.Nav_tree_wrapper ul li').each(function() {
     if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
       $(this).addClass('parent');
     }
   });

   $(".Nav_tree_wrapper ul li.parent > a").hover(
     function() {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
       $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');


     }, function() {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
       $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
     }
   );
 });
```

```css
.Nav_tree_wrapper ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.Nav_tree_wrapper ul li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}
.Nav_tree_wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px groove #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Nav_tree_wrapper">
  <ul id="treeview" class="nav">
    <li>
      <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/SystemAdministration/Admin_Home">System Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/SystemCore/SystemCoreHome">System Core</a>

      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li>
          <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c2/a2">f2</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
          <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c2/a2">f3</a> 
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c4/a4">f4</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c5/a5">f5</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c6/a6">f6</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
          <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c7/a7">f7</a> 
          <ul>
            <li class="parent">
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c8/a8">f8</a> 
              <ul>
                <li class="parent">
                  <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c10/a10">f10</a> 
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c11/a11">f11</a> 
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c9/a9">f9</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
      <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/MyControllerA/MyActionA">MyFunctionA</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li class="parent">
          <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c12/a12">f12</a> 
          <ul style="display: none;">
            <li>
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c13/a13">f13</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
              <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c14%20/a14">f14</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/c16/a16">f16</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MainContent" href="/CourseManagement/CoursesHome">Course Management</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there with your code. You just have to watch for the `li.parent` instead of the `li.parent > a`. So your javascript code could look like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.Nav_tree_wrapper ul li').each(function() {
     if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
       $(this).addClass('parent');
     }
   });

   $(".Nav_tree_wrapper ul li.parent").hover(
     function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
       $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');


     }, function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
       $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
     }
   );
 });
```

And the JS-Fiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/as9fxkLf/1/

### But there is a small problem...

If you've tried the JS-Fiddle, you will instantly see the issue. With multiple sub-levels that open and close only on hover, it becomes very nervous very quickly. You might want to arrange the first (or the second) level of the navigation horizontally instead, so you don't accidentally trigger the hover event too quickly.

Alternatively you could use the jQuery hover intent plugin. It delays the beginning of the hover by a hundred milliseconds:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html